# CXF 2.2.12: How to turn off schema validation on the client side

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I would like to turn off schema validation for JAXB-bound messages.  I am dealing with the client-side CXF code (WSDL first generation).  I have tried using

```
<jaxws:client name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

Without success (see reference [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html) ).  I've had difficulty finding a programmatic way of settings this property.  I've also explored short-circuiting CXF and accessing the parser, unmarshaller, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For CXF 3 I have used this property:

<entry key="set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" value="false"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn off the schema validation you should set the `schema-validation-enabled` property to `false`.

According to documentation referred by you ([CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html)).

To enable schema validation (all requests and responses will be validated against schema) set

```
<entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
```

To disable schema validation (none of the requests nor responses will be validated against schema) do nothing cause it is the default behavior or set

```
<entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Or from the code as follows:

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(XYZSOAPEndPoint);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setAllowChunking(false);
    http.setClient(policy);
    ((BindingProvider)XYZSOAPEndPoint).getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidation.SchemaValidationType.NONE)` put this annotation to your endpoint implementation class

Answer (score 0):

```
@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidation.SchemaValidationType.NONE)
public EndpointImpl endpoint(Bus bus, DirectConnectService accountServiceEndpoint) {
  }
```

put this validation in your endpoint configuration class